# How to use templated child classes by polymorphic base class interface

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, virtual

I have the base Parent class and the templated Child classes.
I'd like to use the Childs in collection to enumerate them by polymorphic interface to the Parent.
I expect virtual (polymorphic) function calls there - but I've got only the static typed call to Parent::print()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Parent {
public:
    Parent() { cout << " parent ctor "; }
    virtual void print() { cout << " Parent::print "; }
};


template <typename T>
class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(T value) : var(value) { cout << " child ctor "; }
    virtual void print() { cout << " Child::print " << var; }
protected:
    T var;
};

int main() {
    Child<int> myChild(1);
    Child<double> myDoubleChild(2.);

    vector<Parent> v = {myChild, myDoubleChild};

    for (auto i : v) {
        i.print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Actual output:

```
 parent ctor  child ctor  parent ctor  child ctor  Parent::print  Parent::print
```

Expected output should contain "Child::print" virtual function calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @tchelidze and @StenSoft there are two flaws:

1. Object Slicing. Lame mistake. std::vector uses raw objects
2. Polymorphism works only with pointers or references

To enable dynamic dispatch code should be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Parent {
public:
    Parent() { cout << " parent ctor "; }
    virtual void print() { cout << " Parent::print "; }
};


template <typename T>
class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(T value) : var(value) { cout << " child ctor "; }
    virtual void print() { cout << " Child::print " << var; }
protected:
    T var;
};

int main() {
    Child<int> myChild(1);
    Child<double> myDoubleChild(2.);

//    vector<Parent> v = {myChild, myDoubleChild};
    vector<Parent*> v = {&myChild, &myDoubleChild};

    for (auto i : v) {
//        i.print();
        i->print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives desired output:

```
parent ctor  child ctor  parent ctor  child ctor  Child::print 1 Child::print 2
```

Comment: You might want to use you smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: @ysdx Thats true, this code works great:

`vector<shared_ptr<Parent>> v = {make_shared<Child<float>>(1), make_shared<Child<int>>(1)};`

Comment: 2. is caused by 1. so it's the same issue

Answer (score 1):

The reason is [Object Slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). 
That is :

> when you assign an object of a subclass to the super class. The superclass knows nothing of the additional information in the subclass, and hasn't got room to store it, so the additional information gets "sliced off"

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism in C++ works on references and pointers only. `vector<Parent>` is a vector of values. These are constructed as copies of the `Child` instances and are all of type `Parent`. Basically what it does is this:

```
vector<Parent> v = { Parent(myChild), Parent(myDoubleChild) };
```

If you would make `Parent` an abstract class (e.g. by changing `print` into pure virtual method), you would see the error.

You need a vector of pointers, e.g.:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Parent>>
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted, object slicing is the problem. An alternative to using a vector of raw pointers is using a vector of [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

> std::reference_wrapper is a class template that wraps a reference in a copyable, assignable object. It is frequently used as a mechanism to store references inside standard containers (like std::vector) which cannot normally hold references

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Parent {
public:
    Parent() { cout << " parent ctor "; }
    virtual void print() { cout << " Parent::print "; }
};


template <typename T>
class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(T value) : var(value) { cout << " child ctor "; }
    virtual void print() { cout << " Child::print " << var; }
protected:
    T var;
};

int main() {
    Child<int> myChild(1);
    Child<double> myDoubleChild(2.);

    typedef std::reference_wrapper<Parent> refType;

    vector<refType> v = {refType(myChild), refType(myDoubleChild)};

    for (auto i : v) {
        i.get().print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this code is:

```
parent ctor  child ctor  parent ctor  child ctor  Child::print 1 Child::print 2
```

It's not that clean (still requires special syntax) but may be considered more idiomatic C++.